# Dropped packets even if rte_eth_rx_burst do not return a full burst

Tags: network-programming, dpdk

I have a weird drop problem, and to understand my question the best way is to have a look at this simple snippet:

```
while( 1 )
{
    if( config->running == false ) {
        break;
    }
    num_of_pkt = rte_eth_rx_burst( config->port_id,
                                   config->queue_idx,
                                   buffers,
                                   MAX_BURST_DEQ_SIZE);
    if( unlikely( num_of_pkt == MAX_BURST_DEQ_SIZE ) ) {
        rx_ring_full = true; //probably not the best name
    }

    if( likely( num_of_pkt > 0 ) )
    {
        pk_captured += num_of_pkt;

        num_of_enq_pkt = rte_ring_sp_enqueue_bulk(config->incoming_pkts_ring,
                                               (void*)buffers,
                                               num_of_pkt,
                                               &rx_ring_free_space);
        //if num_of_enq_pkt == 0 free the mbufs..
     }
}
```

This loop is retrieving packets from the device and pushing them into a queue for further processing by another lcore.

When I run a test with a Mellanox card sending 20M (20878300) packets at 2.5M p/s the loop seems to miss some packets and pk_captured is always like 19M or similar.

rx_ring_full is never true, which means that num_of_pkt is always < MAX_BURST_DEQ_SIZE, so according to the documentation I shall not have drops at HW level. Also, num_of_enq_pkt is never 0 which means that all the packets are enqueued.

Now, if from that snipped I remove the rte_ring_sp_enqueue_bulk call (and make sure to release all the mbufs) then pk_captured is always exactly equal to the amount of packets I've send to the NIC.

So it seems (but I cant deal with this idea) that rte_ring_sp_enqueue_bulk is somehow too slow and between one call to rte_eth_rx_burst and another some packets are dropped due to full ring on the NIC, but, why num_of_pkt (from rte_eth_rx_burst) is always smaller than MAX_BURST_DEQ_SIZE (much smaller) as if there was always sufficient room for the packets?

Note, MAX_BURST_DEQ_SIZE is 512.

**edit 1:**

Perhaps this information might help: the drops seems to be visible also by rte_eth_stats_get, or to be more correct, no drops are reported (imissed and ierrors are 0) but the value of ipackets equals my counter pk_captured (are the missing packets just disappeared??)

**edit 2:**

According to ethtools rx_crc_errors_phy is zero and all the packets are received at PHY level (rx_packets_phy is updated with the correct amount of transferred packets).

The value from rx_nombuf from rte_eth_stats seems to contain trash (this is a print from our test application):

OUT(4): Port 1 stats: ipkt:19439285,opkt:0,ierr:0,oerr:0,imiss:0, rxnobuf:2061021195718

For a transfer of 20M packets, as you can see rxnobuf is garbage OR it has a meaning which I do not understand. The log is generated by:

```
  log("Port %"PRIu8" stats: ipkt:%"PRIu64",opkt:%"PRIu64",ierr:%"PRIu64",oerr:%"PRIu64",imiss:%"PRIu64", rxnobuf:%"PRIu64,
        config->port_id,
        stats.ipackets, stats.opackets,
        stats.ierrors, stats.oerrors,
        stats.imissed, stats.rx_nombuf);
```

where stats came from rte_eth_stats_get.

The packets are not generated on the fly but replayed from an existing PCAP.

**edit 3**

After the answer from Adriy (Thanks!) I've included the xstats output for the Mellanox card, while reproducing the same problem with a smaller set of packets I can see that rx_mbuf_allocation_errors get's updated, but it seems to contain trash:

```
OUT(4): rx_good_packets = 8094164
OUT(4): tx_good_packets = 0
OUT(4): rx_good_bytes = 4211543077
OUT(4): tx_good_bytes = 0
OUT(4): rx_missed_errors = 0
OUT(4): rx_errors = 0
OUT(4): tx_errors = 0
OUT(4): rx_mbuf_allocation_errors = 146536495542
```

Also those counters seems interesting:

```
OUT(4): tx_errors_phy = 0
OUT(4): rx_out_of_buffer = 257156
OUT(4): tx_packets_phy = 9373
OUT(4): rx_packets_phy = 8351320
```

Where rx_packets_phy is the exact amount of packets I've been sending, and summing up rx_out_of_buffer with rx_good_packets I get that exact amount. So it seems that the mbufs get depleted and some packets are dropped.

I made a tweak in the original code and now I'm making a copy of the mbuf from the RX ring using [link](http://dpdk.org/dev/patchwork/patch/6289/) and them releasing immediately the memory, further processing is done on the copy by another lcore. This do not fix the problem sadly, it turns out that to solve the problem I've to disable the packet processing and release also the packet copy (on the other lcore), which make no sense.

Well, will do a bit more investigation, but at least rx_mbuf_allocation_errors seems to need a fix here.

Comment: Have you looked at the statistics for your card with ethtool? Are there any `rx_errors` and if there are, what type (e.g., `rx_crc_errors`, etc.)? How are you sending the packets? Are they replayed from a pcap?

Comment: What about rx_nombuf counter? http://dpdk.org/doc/api/structrte__eth__stats.html#a8afc3f87397701e58b218d9dad03be8c

Comment: So, why do you still think `rx_mbuf_allocation_errors ` is trash? It is a number of failed RX attempts, not the number of dropped buffers, so IMO the number makes sense... And instead of a full mbuf copy, we better just increase the number of buffers in flight.

Comment: Because it takes less than 10 seconds to transfer all the packets, and 146.536.495.542 ( 146 billion ) RX failures in 10 seconds for a 8 Million packets transferred looks a bit weird. But maybe is not, I'm still digging into the details of my test and the MLX driver from DPDK.

Comment: Modern CPUs [do few billion instructions per second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instructions_per_second#Timeline_of_instructions_per_second), so 146 billion checks and increments in 10 seconds sounds OK to me. But sure, it might be a bug... Anyway, since `rx_out_of_buffer` also confirms the cause, do you have any further questions regarding the missing packets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, debugging `rx_nombuf` counter is a way to go. It might look like a garbage, but in fact this counter does not reflect the number of dropped packets (like `ierrors` or `imissed` do), but rather number of failed RX attempts.

Here is a snippet from [MLX5 PMD](http://dpdk.org/browse/dpdk/tree/drivers/net/mlx5/mlx5_rxtx.c#n1765):

```
uint16_t
mlx5_rx_burst(void *dpdk_rxq, struct rte_mbuf **pkts, uint16_t pkts_n)
{
    [...]
    while (pkts_n) {
        [...]
        rep = rte_mbuf_raw_alloc(rxq->mp);
        if (unlikely(rep == NULL)) {
            ++rxq->stats.rx_nombuf;
            if (!pkt) {
                /*
                 * no buffers before we even started,
                 * bail out silently.
                 */
                break;
```

So, the plausible scenario for the issue is as follow:

1. There is a packet in RX queue.
2. There are no buffers in the corresponding mempool.
3. The application polls for new packets, i.e. calls in a loop: `num_of_pkt = rte_eth_rx_burst(...)`
4. Each time we call `rte_eth_rx_burst()`, the `rx_nombuf` counter gets increased.

Please also have a look at `rte_eth_xstats_get()`. For MLX5 PMD there is a hardware `rx_out_of_buffer` counter, which might confirm this theory.

Comment: Thanks, will have a look on that and provide a feedback here. But at first glance is hard to believe that I had 2.061.021.195.718 (2 trillion) failed RX attempts for a 20M (20 million) packet transfer.

Comment: Sure, there are might be some other issues on the way. 2 trillion attempts is a matter of 10-20 minutes on modern CPU in fact. But if the test lasts just for few seconds, you are right, it's something else... Mellanox use bifurcated driver, so those packets might get to kernel when there are no mbufs... Anyway, there is must be a counter which will show the reason.  Normally the `rx_nombuf` must be zero, so is a good lead IMO.

Comment: Hello, I'm in almost same issue. The differences are, in my case, `rx_nombuf` is always `0` and `imissed` is about `0.03%` of received packets even with a throughput of 5Mpps or 14Mpps. Have you any idea?

Comment: @nhnghia sure, please describe as a new question your setup and what have you tried so far and I will have a look...

Comment: Thank you Andriy for your response. Currently I find that `cache_size` when using `rte_pktmbuf_pool_create` to create a mempool may effect the drop. I will try to clarify the issue and possibly describe as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to missing packets will be in changing ring API from **bulk** to **burst**. In dpdk there are 2 modes ring operation bulk and burst. In bulk dequeue mode if the requested elements are 32, and there are 31 elements the API returns 0.

I have faced similar issue too.